# Supabase sessions with NextJS SSR/SGR?

Tags: next.js, supabase

I'm wondering if it is currently possible to have Supabase work with both server + client rendering. It seems as though we must generally choose one or the other, but NextJS allows one to define SSG (server-side generated), SSR (server-side rendered), and CSR (client-side rendered) pages.

For example, the [webapp example](https://supabase.com/docs/guides/getting-started/tutorials/with-nextjs) for NextJS + Supabase seems to indicate that we should SessionContextProvider; however, wrapping the entire app in this context provider requires useState, which to my understanding will render the entire app as client-side rendered.

Supabase has a [server-side rendering solution](https://supabase.com/docs/guides/auth/server-side-rendering), but then this seems to require us to manually handle components/pages that we want to render client-side. For each component that requires authentication, we would need to explicitly make a session call, which seems unnecessarily excessive.

With the NextJS-13 beta, we can explicitly define server components, and it seems Supabase has a [beta solution](https://supabase.com/docs/guides/auth/auth-helpers/nextjs-server-components#authentication) too. However, I was wondering if it is currently possible to do this without the beta?

Answer (score 0):

> Wrapping the entire app in this context provider requires useState, which to my understanding will render the entire app as client-side rendered.

No, it won't cause the entire app to be CSR. The use of React hooks on `pages` folder components (including `_app.js`) won't cause the page to be client-side rendered, it will still be pre-rendered (as long as there are no blocking data requirements, e.g. using `getServerSideProps` or `getInitialProps` in the case of `_app.js`, see [Automatic Static Optimization](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/automatic-static-optimization)) and then sent to the client to be hydrated. This is also true for pages/components marked as client-components on Next.js v13 `app` directory feature, they will still be pre-rendered.

The only way in which Next.js won't server-render a component is if using [dynamic imports](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/dynamic-import) and setting `ssr` to `false` (doesn't apply for page components).

Comment: I see, thank you! If that is the case, what is the purpose of NextJS moving towards server components? I'm trying to think of instances where one would explicitly only want certain components to be rendered client-side, but I can't immediately think of anything that can't be done currently.

Comment: There are several purposes/advantages. One of the most important things is reduced client-side bundle. Dependencies used on server components remain in the server. Also, the ability to retrieve data server-side, thus keeping secrets away from the client (server components can be used as regular async functions). Regarding your last question, think of a component that is dependent on some browser API to render something, without disabling `ssr`, you would likely end up with a hydration error.